# Pivot table continues to be linked to old workbook

Tags: excel

I have a work book with two pivot tables in it. The pivots get their data from a sheet within the work book *(say workbook 1)*.

I create a copy of workbook 1 (ctrl +c , ctrl+v). And rename the new work book as workbook 2. Now within work book 2 the pivots continue to remain linked to workbook 1. I've not seen this issue earlier.

I am using excel version 2013

Comment: If you haven't this earlier, it is most probably because you didn't check (no accusation, just a guess). This is a long time behavior and there is nothing surprising about it! ;)

Comment: @R3uK is correct about this having been this way a while (since Office '03 at least). As far as a fix, nothing complicated, just have to manually update the Data Source for the tables (probably easiest to just delete the workbook portion of the range rather than reselecting)